# What are the consequences of running scripts from ajax loaded pages?

Tags: javascript, ajax, single-page-application

I built/manage an SPA (single-page application) interface. It doesn't use modern frameworks like VueJS or React... It uses AJAX.

It's a custom interface that loads parts of the pages through ajax. When you click an item to edit, a window on page or modal is opened and all the HTML and JS dependencies of that specific page from AJAX is injected into the page. When a new page is loaded, the existing html is replaced (I do jQuery for most of the actual functionality) with like `html(new_content)`

**Potential Problem:**

Inside these ajax loaded pages, it runs javascript, for instance, "attach to this button on click", "initiates a datatables class" for the content being loaded into tables etc. When another page is loaded, it replaces the existing content from the previous, the new page loads its own JS again.

1) **Unique variables** loaded from the Ajax pages still exist even after a new page is loaded from ajax. (looking the variables in the console show they exist), I am assuming loading variables with the same name get replaced with new values.

2) **Functions/Classes** that are being added are still embedded in the memory even after I've asked it to delete everything

*Another example*, if I ran a `setInterval()` timer, after a new page is
loaded and it replaces existing content, the setInterval is still
running.

What are your thoughts here? If the user doesn't reload the actual page by using the browser refresh, then loading these ajax pages over and over again will ultimately drain the memory of the client's device?

**Is there a way to keep a clean slate after each page is loaded so existing variables loaded in memory are erased?** Or do I make sure each page being loaded is wrapped into an anonymous function that is cleared after each page is loaded?

Comment: To sounds like you pollute the global scope, and that's something you should never do. So yes have to make sure that all your code `...is wrapped into an anonymous function[s]...` and only those parts are exposed that really need to. And about the `setInterval` or similar things, if you unload a page you should provide a cleanup script for that page, that cleans everything up the gc cant do by its own.

Comment: And about the `[...]then loading these ajax pages over and over again will ultimately drain the memory of the client's device[..]` if that's the case then your loading strategy is wrong.

Comment: @t.niese That is a good point. I should provide a cleanup method for all pages being loaded for the cause I want to unload.

Comment: @t.niese another concern is loading `on()` methods. attaching to buttons/links etc based on triggers/clicks. If I load another page, those attached triggers are still running arent they? Which is essentially what the cleanup method should clear up?